# Prepared statement is failing

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a forum. In this prepared statement, I am trying to get get the forum_topic and forum_posts. Furthermore in this code I am trying to see the posts made for an individual topic, just like if you are looking at my topic on here and you see the posts(comments).

I am getting the correct values for `$tid` and `$cid`. I believe the issue has to be with the my prepare part of this, but I am not too sure. I get the else statement...

```
echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
```

But it is an actual topic and should have a post with it.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

My full code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

//Prepare
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();


    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onclick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }

foreach($stmt as $row) {

    //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
    if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
    //var_dump($stmt2);

        $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }   
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
}       
}   else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I thought it might help to show the database tables that I am trying to pull from.

```
forum_topics
CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topic_title` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `topic_creator` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topic_last_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `topic_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `topic_reply_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `topic_views` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c

forum_posts
CREATE TABLE `forum_posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `post_creator` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `post_content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c
```

Comment: What is the result when you submit the query directly using phpMyAdmin or similar? Do you get any errors, or the result?

Comment: I get this... `SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1' at line 1 `

Comment: I mean when you replace the placeholders with the query strings!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Yes, I do `id
category_id
topic_title
topic_creator
topic_last_user
topic_date
topic_reply_date
topic_views

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
7
1
Paul topic test
1
NULL
2015-07-20 20:42:50
2015-07-20 20:42:50
0
`

Comment: You seem to be mixing mysqli_ Procedural and OO functions. You also are using the wrong statement handle on `while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {` I think it shoudl be `$stmt2` and it probably should be `$stmt2->fetch()` or `$stmt2->fetch_assoc()`anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly Gotcha, didn't see that, you mean to change it to `while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2)) {` ? Where am I mixing the OO and Procedural statements at?

Comment: The `while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {` is proceedural, all ( I think) of the rest is OO. See second part of previous comment

Comment: I changed that line to `while ($stmt2->fetch()) {` and `while ($stmt2->fetch_assoc()) {` and the result is the same. I am getting the else saying that the topic doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you bind the result columns to variable? I dont think so.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83979/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-paul).

Comment: Try a quick tutorial, [this one seems quite straight forward](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage) It will pay dividend in no time. You could also indent your code in a sensible fashion then both you and us could read and understand it better

Comment: I changed these line to this... `$stmt->bind_results($category_id, $forum_topics_id);
  $stmt->fetch($category_id, $forum_topics_id);` and am getting this error for the bind_results line `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_results()`